# HTTP Post to bin/bash script

Tags: bash

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
read POST_STRING;
```

What i am trying to do?

I would like to make a HTTP POST to `myscript.sh` and receive the POST data there read it make some `echo` for the test and trigger the script ot receiving the POST request.

I am not quite sure this is possible. I'm using ubuntu and i have `php5` and `apache2` installed. I was making some searching and decided to install `php5-cgi` module but i am not quite sure i need it.

Can you please point me in the right direction, is it even possible ?

Comment: `php5-cgi` only helps for PHP scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to have [mod_cgi enabled in apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html)

Then you can create a cgi-bin directory in the root directory of your web server with a script like :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo

if [ -z "$QUERY_STRING" ]
    then
    echo "POST METHOD <br>"
    read QUERY_STRING
else 
    echo "GET METHOD <br>"
fi
echo $QUERY_STRING
```

and testing with sending some form data with GET or POST method.

Comment: Your approach seems interesting. I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: I think you mistyped `if [ -z "$QUERY_STRING" ]` - be *very* careful about quoting variables when dealing with untrusted inputs!

Comment: yes you are right. this is aimed for demonstration only. Will edit

Comment: It's strange. When i try to make a POST request to this script via POSTMAN i get as response all the content inside the script. The same happens when i try to open the direct link to the script via the browser. Is there any special permissions needed except 'chmod +x' for the file ?

Comment: cgi-bin directory and your file must have +x but not w for every body

Comment: but it can also mean that mod_cgi is not properly enabled